# Difference between glm with sandwich package and glmrob for Poisson distribution

Tags: r, glm, poisson

I´m having some doubts with  `glmrob`(package: robustbase). I want to use glmrob to get the same results as I was having with glm + sandwich.

I was writing:

```
p_3 <- glm(formula = var1~ var2, 
           family = poisson(link=log), 
           data = p3,
           na.action = na.omit)

coeftest(p_3, vcov = sandwich)
```

Both variables are categorical. `var1` has two categories and `var2` has four.

Now I'm trying to use glmrob to get everything in the same step:

```
p_2 <- glmrob(formula = var1~ var2, 
              family = poisson (link=log), 
              data = p3,
              na.action = na.omit,
              method= "Mqle",
              control = glmrobMqle.control(tcc= 1.2)
)
```

`summary(p2)`and `summary(p_3)`don´t yield the same results so I think that I need to make some changes to this two lines `method= "Mqle",control = glmrobMqle.control(tcc= 1.2)`but I don´t really know which ones.

Maybe I have to use  `method="MT"` as it works for Poisson models, but I´m not sure.

Comment: I really don't think you should be using Poisson regression for a categorical dependent variable. It just doesn't make sense. Can you please try to explain what you are trying to model?

Comment: Can you post the output from the two models?

Answer (score 0):

The outputs:

With glmrob:

```
summary(p2)

>Call:  glmrob(formula = dummy28_n ~ coexistencia, family = poisson(link = log),      data = p3, na.action = na.omit, method = "Mqle", control = glmrobMqle.control(tcc = 1.2)) 


>Coefficients:
                                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)                                -1.7020     0.5947  -2.862  0.00421 **
coexistenciaPobreza energética              1.1627     0.9176   1.267  0.20514   
coexistenciaInseguridad residencial         0.7671     0.6930   1.107  0.26830   
coexistenciaCoexistencia de inseguridades   1.3688     0.6087   2.249  0.02453 * 
---
>Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Robustness weights w.r * w.x: 
 143 weights are ~= 1. The remaining 3 ones are
    71    124    145 
0.6266 0.6266 0.6266 

>Number of observations: 146 
Fitted by method ‘Mqle’  (in 8 iterations)

>(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

>No deviance values available 
Algorithmic parameters: 
   acc    tcc 
0.0001 1.2000 
maxit 
   50 
test.acc 
  "coef"
```

with glm and sandwich:

```
coef <- coeftest(p_3, vcov = sandwich)
coef


z test of coefficients:

                                          Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                               -1.79176    0.52705 -3.3996 0.0006748 ***
coexistenciaPobreza energética             1.09861    0.72648  1.5122 0.1304744    
coexistenciaInseguridad residencial        0.69315    0.60093  1.1535 0.2487189    
coexistenciaCoexistencia de inseguridades  1.32972    0.53259  2.4967 0.0125349 *  

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
´´´
```